# "Sign in as different user" code not working

Tags: sharepoint-server, c-sharp

I am trying to implement the functionality for "Sign in as different user" link button on my custom access denied page in sharepoint 2010 using the below code

```
string site = base.Web.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
Response.Redirect("~/" + site + "/_layouts/closeConnectionNew.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true");
```

but it is not working. I also tried calling the javascript funtion with the following code but of no use. What am I missing?

```
string site = base.Web.ServerRelativeUrl.ToString();
 string urlforsign = "~/" + site + "/_layouts/closeConnectionNew.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true";
urlforsign = urlforsign.Replace("/", "\u002f");
 Response.Redirect("javascript:LoginAsAnother('" + urlforsign + "', 1)");
```

Comment: Your url seems  incorrent. It should be "_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true"

Comment: @VishalM.Patil I made a copy of closeConnection.aspx so that I could  modify it if required

Comment: It is not working with closeConnection.aspx as well.

Comment: Remove "~/" and Get site url as string site = SPWeb.Url.ToString(); and try.

Comment: @VishalM.Patil tried replacing"~/" with string site = SPWeb.Url.ToString();, but it did not work.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it's working:

```
weburl + "/_layouts/closeConnection.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true"
```

Comment: not working using the weburl also

Comment: There is also one change here from your code. Here 'closeConnection.aspx' and not 'closeConnectionNew.aspx' ,. so try with that ..

Comment: Please note that closeConnection.aspx is a copy of closeConnection.aspx. I had already tried the code with closeConnection.aspx. Since I have created the custom access denied page, hence I decide to copy the closeConnection.aspx and perform any chenges in the copy if required

Comment: I redirects to the correct path i.e. "http://siteName/_layouts/accessdenied.aspx?loginasanotheruser=true" as mentioned in closeConnection.aspx but no prompt shows up for the user to enter credentials